# Hosted library URIs from Google

Tags: jquery

This isn't a specific coding question *per se*, but I noticed something recently which has me scratching my head.

In the Google hosted libraries, they used to provide full URL strings. I was working on a site, and my jQuery wasn't loading, so I went and looked at my links in the document head. I noticed that it was missing the `http:` prefix. I couldn't figure out why it wasn't there, other than I had probably copied it wrong. When I went back and looked at the site, I noticed none of the source URI's had the prefix. I've also noticed that YouTube is now doing the same thing.

Can someone help me understand why they do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a protocol relative (or schemaless) URI. If you're pointing to it from a HTTP site, it will point to `HTTP://uri`, if you're using HTTPS:// it will point to `HTTPS://uri`.

[More information here](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense and it what my guess was, but wasn't sure about. I'm glad this article makes note of the locally-hosted errors, which is where I first caught it. Thanks!